# Brazil mobile number validation with node js

Tags: node.js

I am using "**ng-intl-tel-input**" for validating Brazil mobile numbers.
It works fine for area code (11). But for (61) it is not accepting 11 digits. I have tried with this number **(+55)(61)986543211** and it throws "Invalid" error.

Can someone help me to solve this? Also get some testable brazil mobile numbers.

Comment: share your code

Comment: can you please provide a script that you have done so far...

Comment: you can use this RegEx ^(?:(55\d{2})|\d{2})[6-9]\d{8}$